# Check if the data exist in a dropdown?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

So I created a dropdown like the following:

```
<select style="width: 100%" ng-model="selectPosition" ng-Change="GetPosition(selectPosition)">
        <option value="Partner">Partner</option>
        <option value="Associate">Associate</option>
        <option value="Council">Council</option>
</select>
```

In my controller, I make the option from the dropdown selected depending on the data. Now I want to check if the data exist in that dropdown. How do I do that?

```
$scope.selectPosition = $scope.Data.CompanyTitle;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your options using [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in selectOptions track by item.id" ng-model="selectPosition"></select>
```

Then you will be able to loop through selectOptions and check.

Comment: this is adding dynamic options to the dropdown right?

Comment: Yes. You can also have a static list in controller

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this using angularjs than you have to use ng-options to check whether or not there is data in "select".

or your can do like this also in your controller.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].children.length
```

or `document.getElementById('select')[0].children.length`

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Simple check selectPosition != null || '' || undefined